Inductance to Digital Converter LC tank design issue
I'm designing a proximity sensing system based on this LDC by Texas Instrument.
In this context, I realized a simple LC tank with L = 23uH, Rs = 3.27 Ohm and a C = 1,5 nF.
The frequency response of the LC tank is similar to the one in the following figure.

I need to prevent possible interferences affect my measurements between INA INB pin and my LC Tank.
How I can manage this? Should I use some filters, or in general, how I can improve the stopband attenuation of this LC tank in order to reach about -40db before 700 kHz and after 1 MHz?
Every suggestion are strongly accepted.

What type of interference are you expecting ?

@citizen the environment has some strong electromagnetic interference up to 700kHz and after 1 MHz

Can you possibly increase inductor Quality factor? It is now about 36, which yields $ R_P 4.44k $ (much lower than 90k allowed by LDC1101). This will tighten bandwidth.

@glen_geek quite difficult , since It Is about 6 cm x 6 cm Square , 10 turns , 0.5 mm width, 1mm spacing.

To get that kind of selectivity, you would have to improve your Q factor from where it is now (about 38) to over 300, which is equivalent to reducing the resistance to about 0.4 Ω.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

From a comment:

I have 6 cm x 6 cm Square coil, 10 turns , 0.5 mm width, 1mm spacing.

That must be a PCB coil then.
0.5 mm track width in 1 oz. (35 um) copper is equivalent to AWG 34.6 wire.
Your planar coil has a total length of about 3 meters.
It should have a resistance of about 0.96 ohms/meter, giving a total
resistance of 3 m × 0.96 Ω/m = 2.88 Ω.
There are ways to improve your coil design:

Make the tracks wider and the space between them smaller.
Use both sides of the PCB, putting half the turns on each side.

If you instead wind the coil out of AWG 26 magnet wire, the total resistance will be only about 0.3 Ω.

This is about all I can tell you, based on what you've told us so far about your application requirements.

What are you trying to sense with such a large coil?
What are your overall accuracy requirements?
How badly is the external interference affecting the accuracy?


quite difficult to.improve It a lot. For Now I have  6 cm x 6 cm Square coil, 10 turns , 0.5 mm width, 1mm spacing.

Thank you for your suggestion. I'll try. By the way, to answer your question: 1) I need to detect a stainless steel block transit, that can happen at quite high speed. 2) not a specific frequency difference, high enough to discriminate the transit. The external interference can strongly increase the voltage that the LDC read at frequency outside the range of natural oscillation. With -40dB we should suppress those disturbs.

ALso decreasing the Rs , the attenuation is not -40dB.
